# Why author name is not printing in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Why author name is not printing in swift? I'm new in swift and trying to build a  feeds UI using UIKit, and trying to fetch API and displaying author name with the image in each tableview cell, Can you help me to that? currently its not displaying any thing what can be the issue?

ImageViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ImageViewController: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier = "ImageTableViewCell"
    
    private let profileImageView: UIImageView = {
        let imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        return imageView
    }()
    
     let authorLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.textColor = .white
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 16)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.text = "eaeafafa"
        return label
    }()

    override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        contentView.addSubview(profileImageView)
        contentView.addSubview(authorLabel)

        let profileImageConstraints = [
            profileImageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
            profileImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 14),
            profileImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -14),
            profileImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 400),
            profileImageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
        ]
    
       
        let authorLabelConstraints = [
        authorLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
         authorLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: profileImageView.bottomAnchor, constant: 10)
        ]
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(authorLabelConstraints)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate(profileImageConstraints)
    }
    
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
}
```

FeedImage:

```
import Foundation


struct FeedImage: Codable, Identifiable {
    let id, author: String
    let width, height: Int
    let url, downloadURL: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case id, author, width, height, url
        case downloadURL = "download_url"
    }
}
```

ViewController:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    private var viewModel = FeedModel()

    private let tableView: UITableView = {
        let tableView = UITableView()
        tableView.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.register(ImageViewController.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: ImageViewController.identifier)
        tableView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return tableView
    }()

    private let feedsLabel: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Feeds"
        label.textColor = .black
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 40, weight: .bold)
        return label
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        view.addSubview(feedsLabel)
        viewModel.fetchData()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            tableView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: feedsLabel.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            tableView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            tableView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
        ])
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            feedsLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 100),
            feedsLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 20)
        ])
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.viewModel.images.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: ImageViewController.identifier, for: indexPath) as? ImageViewController else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
        
        let image = viewModel.images[indexPath.row]
        
        cell.authorLabel.text = image.author
        
        return cell
    }


}
```

FeedModel:

```
import Foundation

class FeedModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var images = [FeedImage]()
    
    init() {
        fetchData()
    }
    
    func fetchData() {
        let API: String =  "https://picsum.photos/v2/list?page=2&limit=100"
        
        guard let url: URL = URL(string: API) else { return }
        
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
           if let error = error {
               print("Error \(error)")
                return
            }
            
            if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
                print("\(response.statusCode)")
                 return
            }
            
            guard let data = data else { return }
            
            do {
                let images = try JSONDecoder().decode([FeedImage].self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                   self.images = images
                    print("Fetched images with authors:", images)

                }
            } catch let error {
                print(error)
            }
        }.resume()
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's related to your issue but I don't think ObservableObject and @Published is of any relevance when using UIKit but only when using SwiftUI.

Comment: @Joakim Danielson Yes, Then how to do things in UIKit? Actually i build same app using SwiftUI and now trying to do same thing with UIKit myself.

Comment: I guess your fetchData() method needs a completion handler so you can call `tableView.reloadData()` once the function has downloaded the data. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple problems but none of them are unfixable :-)

1., first of all, you have a unnecessary early return in your FeedModel. The response will be always a `HTTPURLResponse` so if you call return your result will be not handled.

```
if let response = response as? HTTPURLResponse {
    print("\(response.statusCode)")
    return // <- HERE - remove this
}
```

2., In UIKit you have to manually observe your data. So even if your `FeedModel` is an `ObservableObject` it will not notify your ViewController about the dataset changes. There are multiple ways to solve this problem, but if your `images` array is already a @Published property then you can (and you have to) subscribe the changes of it.

So please add these to you viewController and don't forget to call the `subscribe` function from `viewDidLoad`:

```
import Combine
private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

private func subscribe() {
    viewModel
        .$images
        .sink { [weak self] _ in
            self?.tableView.reloadData()
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
}
```

3., Now your code will work but I think there will be constraint problems. Probably you'll need to add `tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension` when instantiating the tableView. Also worth noting that the author label's textColor is white so it can be the same color as the background color.